# Microsoft Shifts API - Unable to get people on shifts between 8am to 5PM when timestamp is 3PM

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm stuck with an issue where with Microsoft Shifts API I am unable to find people on shift when I look for 3 PM, see below API call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/${route.teamId}/schedule/shifts?$filter=sharedShift/startDateTime ge ${requestData.startDateTimestamp} and sharedShift/endDateTime le ${requestData.startDateTimestamp}
```

So if startDateTimestamp is for 3 PM that day, it will not return anyone on shift between 8am to 5pm .. How can we do that? Or if someone is on shift from 1PM to 5PM.

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't tried anything in this endpoint, so I might well be way off, but this sounds very likely to be something to do with a UTC time issue. What time zone is your request in? What time zone is the main tenant in? Perhaps you need to be sending a UTC time query?

Comment: @Julian, are you still facing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be a timezone problem. Please try running it with time in UTC instead of local time and see if the problem persists. If so please share the response/error.